# Multiple lines on Card

Tags: trello, formatting

When I attempt to <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to move to another line, It actually is creating a new card? Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

While it's not possible to put in line breaks, since the columns / cards are fixed width, you can easily work around this limitation by just adding some white space until you fill in the line and the text naturally jumps to the next line.

Normal spaces will get ignored though, so go for something like ideographic space (just grab it from inside these square brackets): ]　[ or go hunting [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Answer (score 0):

Trello cards are single-line. You can use line breaks on the description or comments.

Comment: Can you give an example of what to enter in?

Comment: You can't make a line break on a card. Once you've created the card, click on it to see description or comment options. You can use line breaks in those.

Comment: Just asking for an example of a line break in the answer.

Comment: @Dez You can't make line breaks in cards. There is no way to give an example, because it can't be done.

Comment: But the answer you gave says you can. Typo in the question?

Comment: @Dez No it doesn't. Read the answer. You cannot make a line break in a card (they are single-line and just word-wrap), But you can make line breaks in the description or comments in the card.

Answer (score 0):

Trello card *titles* **do not respect Markdown** (so having two spaces before pressing enter will not create a line break), but they will overflow to two or more lines if they are too long for a single line.  (As mentioned above, the description and comments on the "back" of the card support line feeds.)

When resizing the board, you can expect this line wrapping in the card title to change as well.  It would be nice to have a way to force a line feed in the middle of a card title, but I can't find one at this point.